# Pause absolutely all processes in Flash game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Like when pressing (not clicking!!!) the  windows |X| button on the game window. Is that possible? Or will I have to write custom pause function? :S I have a very complicated program, and now I want to add PAUSE button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your game loop (before updating), just add a check for a "pause" state. If paused, don't update. Should be pretty easy to implement.

-Justin

Comment: This is the method I recommend. One game loop updating EVERYTHING. However, this requires that all logic is running in the game loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sorry to say but you will have to add your own pause function. Flash does have a MovieClip::pause() function, but that only pause the frame animation, not the rest of the code execution.

Answer (score 1):

If you've set an event listener for enterframe (like you should have), you can remove the listener during a pause, and add it back when unpaused. It will freeze the game on the exact frame when you paused.

Comment: It's not that easy, I've got too many listeners... As I said, the game is rather complicated :S I'd rather try @justinS method. Thank you anyway.

Comment: That's fine. But you should only have a single enterframe listener, that calls every other update method, if only for this reason alone. But also many, many more. Don't forget to select the answer that worked for you.

Comment: @sold out activist: what about other listeners like for mouse or keyboard?

Comment: Ideally, you want to limit widespread listeners, using a controller such as your main class. But only the enterframe listener presents a possible FPS drain by having multiple listeners working independently.